# Java-Sqlite Truncate all Database tables

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, netbeans

How to Truncate All Tables in Sqlite Database using Java?

I know i can do this

```
{
    ...
     String table_name1 = "Delete From table_name1";
     String table_name2 = "Delete From table_name2";
     String table_name3 = "Delete From table_name3";
     String table_name4 = "Delete From table_name4";
     String table_name5 = "Delete From table_name5";
     stmt.executeUpdate(table_name1);
    ...
 }
```

I can execute all these Strings to do the task but it increases the Lines of Code.

Is there a way to Truncate all tables in a Database with a single command, without separately typing there names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no `TRUNCATE` in sqlite. You can use `DELETE FROM <tablename>` to delete all table contents. You'll need to do that separately for each table.

However, if you're interested in removing all data, consider just deleting the database file and creating a new one.

Comment: wow recreating database has attracted my attention :p, for now i'll do that.

Answer (score 3):

`SQLite` do not have `TRUNCATE TABLE` command in `SQLite` but you can use `SQLite DELETE` command to delete complete data from an existing table, though it is recommended to use `DROP TABLE` command to drop complete table and re-create it once again.

Try

```
{
    ...
     String table_name1 = "DELETE FROM table_name1";
     String table_name2 = "DELETE FROM  table_name2";
     String table_name3 = "DELETE FROM table_name3";
     String table_name4 = "DELETE FROM table_name4";
     String table_name5 = "DELETE FROM table_name5";
     stmt.executeUpdate(table_name1);
   ...
}
```